# How to create scoping for utility method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scoping

I want to write a utility class that will hold several methods that will be used throughout my code.

say `Util.sayHi("Maxim") // Hi Maxim` but I want to try avoid pulling the global scope, and the possibility that someone would override my method.

I see jQuery has a solution to this problem https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ how do they do that?

I'm working with React, and ES6 / ES7 transformers so new JS features are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are using ES6, the solution is trivial: use **modules**. They're designed to do exactly this.

```
// util.js
export function sayHi(name) {
    console.log("Hi "+name);
}
```

```
// somewhereelse.js
import * as Util from "util.js";
Util.sayHi("Maxim");
```

You're not polluting global scope at all, and the variables you are exporting are not writable from outside the module.